# Orchard Dynamic Forms throwing Error: TypeError: $.validator.unobtrusive is undefined , Lib.js , Line 1266 col 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, orchardcms, orchard-modules

While using ORchard.Dynamic Forms, I noticed in the "Console" that there is an error thrown in "Lib.js" file used by ORchard Dynamic Forms:

TypeError: $.validator.unobtrusive is undefined , Lib.js , Line 1266 col 4

Can someone please help me get rid of this error ?

Comment: Orchard 1.9.1,  I downloaded from here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Dynamic Forms only. All the Jquery.Validate scripts are loaded by Orchard Dynamic Forms at runtime.

There is an issue on GitHub which mentions a similar issue as yours. Check it here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/5575

Can you check with Orchard  Solution at Location: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/tree/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.DynamicForms

As you will observe, there is an Assets.json file present while in 1.9.1, there is NO Assets.json as downloaded from the release page you have mentioned in your comments.

Comment: Thanks this did helped me understand further